# RDP disabled but still logging successful connections on disabled accounts

Tags: windows-7, windows, remote-desktop, terminal-services

Since i was suspicious about unauthorized RDP connections on my computer, I disabled the RDP service to make sure nobody could access my computer any more.

After this, I checked the logs in `Microsoft\TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager\Operational` and `Microsoft\TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager\Operational`.

In `Microsoft\TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager\Operational`, RDP was still receiving successful connections to my personal account, even if RDP was disabled. Actually it has always had received successful connections to my own account, but i never experienced being logged out from this. example :

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager" Guid="{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}" /> 
  <EventID>21</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x1000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-02-03T14:38:48.587069400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>3186</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="644" ThreadID="980" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyComputer</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="XXXXXXXX" /> 
  </System>
- <UserData>
- <EventXML xmlns:auto-ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns="Event_NS">
  <User>MyComputer\MyUser</User> 
  <SessionID>1</SessionID> 
  <Address>LOCAL</Address> 
  </EventXML>
  </UserData>
  </Event>
```

And yet RDP is disabled and i have not been logged out at any moment.

In `Microsoft\TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager\Operational` i saw many users authenticated, such as `administrator` account, which is disabled, and an account named `john` (and there's no such users registered on my computer). example :

```
- <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
- <System>
  <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager" Guid="{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}" /> 
  <EventID>1149</EventID> 
  <Version>0</Version> 
  <Level>4</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Opcode>0</Opcode> 
  <Keywords>0x1000000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-02-02T22:29:49.155951400Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>55095</EventRecordID> 
  <Correlation /> 
  <Execution ProcessID="456" ThreadID="5220" /> 
  <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational</Channel> 
  <Computer>MyComputer</Computer> 
  <Security UserID="XXXXXX" /> 
  </System>
- <UserData>
- <EventXML xmlns:auto-ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events" xmlns="Event_NS">
  <Param1>administrator</Param1> 
  <Param2 /> 
  <Param3>aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd</Param3> 
  </EventXML>
  </UserData>
  </Event>
```

This record was logged as successful, even though `administrator` is disabled.

How bad is this? ?